# JourneyBuilder Update Contact activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, activities

I am attempting to update a contact record using the Update Contact activity in Journey Builder. The attribute I wish to update is a date field. Is it possible to update with the current date?

The UI makes it seem that you select a static date for this field. Thank you!

Comment: I've also tried this, but with no success. It doesn't appear to like any AMPscript input either. This leads me to believe it isn't possible, but somebody else may have insight.

Comment: It allows you to enter `getDate()`, but it just gets set to a static date.

Comment: I have nothing of substance to add here other than me rolling my eyes that this product is so poorly designed.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with Data Binding, it's not a great workaround, but it's the only way [today]. Here's what you need to do.

1. Create a DE with a ContactKey and Date field
2. Create a Query Activity to add all records from your Event Source DE (or all Contacts in your Population/root Attribute Set) to the DE you created in step 1, setting the current date as `GETDATE()` in your SQL query.
3. Add the Query Activity in step 2 to an automation to run daily.
4. Create a 1:1 cardinal relationship in Contact Builder, linking the DE you created in step 1 to the Contact Record.
5. Add the following string in the Update Contact Data value field: `{{Contact.Attribute.InsertDENameFromStep1.InsertDEDateFieldFromStep1}}`

Where `InsertDENameFromStep1` is the name of the DE you created and `InsertDEDateFieldFromStep1` is the name of the DE field. Note that if your data extension name or DE field contains spaces, then you will need to surround the DE and/or field name with "quotation marks".

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem possible to use Data Binding for a date field. You can enter the code but it doesn't save - gets reset to a static date value instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have an other way but you need developement, it needs to develop a **custom activity** in JourneyBuilder and in it you can update the contact's date as you wish just by when they are passing by your activity, update the date field with the current date taken on your custom activity server. Ta daaa ! But you need to know how to develop a custom activity which is not simple at first sight.